# BigCommerce: Adding countdown timer to specific product detail pages

Tags: javascript, html, bigcommerce

I'm interested in adding a countdown timer in javascript to specific product detail pages.  However, when I try to add my custom JS to the product description html source editor it doesn't seem to accept it.  Could anyone advise me where or what is the best way of implementing a feature like this?

Comment: Provide any material and/or code you have attempted and research you have done.

Comment: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

`<div id="getting-started"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#getting-started")
  .countdown("2017/01/01", function(event) {
    $(this).text(
      event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
    );
  });
</script>`

Comment: added this html in the product description html source editor and added the countdown javascript src in footer scripts

Comment: You need `jQuery` as it is a `jQuery Plugin`. Add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` into `<head>` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by using BigCommerce's new Script Manager.  Created a new script and added the following code:

```
<script>
var deadline = new Date("Jan 5, 2019 15:37:25").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {
var now = new Date().getTime();
var t = deadline - now;
var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((t%(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))/(1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
if (document.getElementById("countdown")){
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    if (t < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}
}, 1000);
</script>
```

After saving the script, you are able to edit the html for whatever product you would like and add a new div with the countdown id.

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
```